# Replacing indeterminate values to 1.0 in python

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, infinity

Is there any way to change python computations to automatically replace indeterminate values such as `float("inf") * 0` and `float("inf") / float("inf")` with `1.0` whenever encountered? I know that I can put if conditions using`math.isnan()` and replace the value manually in the code, but, is there any automatic way to do it?

Comment: @Sujay It's a Python thing where you can create Infinity this way. Correct as is

Comment: I think float("inf") is a floating point number.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that @NatthaphonHongchareon

Comment: You could implement your own numerical datatype by defining the required operators and unary functions. In these operators and functions, you could check for such conditions. ... but it will be comparable slow.

Comment: @PrameshKumar Shouldn't `float("inf") * 0` becomes `0` instead of `1`. If so the easiest thing to do is replace `float("inf")` with some number. Same number for all `float("inf")`

Comment: In python, `float("inf") * 0` becomes `nan`. I can set `float("inf")` to a high number, but then the answer would be `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: FYI, this is called presubstitution and [has been advocated by William Kahan](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310130507/http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Grail.pdf) but is generally not supported in many floating-point implementations except by trapping exceptions and manually substituting the desired result.

Comment: @Natthaphon Hongcharoen No, float("inf") * 0 should not "become" 0.  As the question correctly states, it is indeterminate, in float-speak "nan", Not A Number (in the "real world" we might be able to use L'Hopital's Rule to "determine" it).  I think Eric is right, you'd need to hard code this "fix".